# how to jump to a custom dialog box from another custom dialog box

Tags: android, customdialog

In my app when user clicks a button, it pops up a dialog box. Then upon clicking submit button in the dialog box it opens another dialog box. The problem i'm facing in this scenario is that upon clicking the button of first dialog box it is showing second dialog box but it is not closing the first one And the second problem is that the second dialog box is having an Edittext box and upon using edittext.getText() it is not getting input string.

showCustomDialog() is method to open first dialog box

```
   protected void showCustomDialog() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CallBlockerBlacklistViewActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.blockoptionsdialog);


            Button button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);    
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    selectContactFromDevice();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.manual);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showManualDialog();

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }  


protected void showManualDialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CallBlockerBlacklistViewActivity.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.manualentry);

        final EditText manual_edittext=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.manualedittext);
        Log.d("txtB" , String.valueOf(manual_edittext));


        manual_number=manual_edittext.getText().toString();


        Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                addtolist(manual_number);



                dialog.dismiss();
            }


        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

addtolist is not passing the required number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer #1 is pretty easy:  You only have dialog.dismiss() in your first on click, but not your second.

```
        Button button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);    
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectContactFromDevice();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.manual);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showManualDialog();

            }
        });
```

Answer #2 is that you are calling getText in your viewCreation.  You need to wait for the user to input text, and hit the button.  Move the getText() inside your onClick() like so:

```
    Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //This line needs to go inside.
            String manual_number=manual_edittext.getText().toString();

            addtolist(manual_number);

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: the first dialog box opening method is  showCustomDialog()! and i've added dialog.dismiss in it.